# How can I prevent Google Play from installing apps on my Android device when asked to do so from a browser?

Tags: android, security, google-play, google-play-services

I have an Android phone which, in its stock ROM, comes with Google Play and (presumably) Google Play Services.

If I log into the Google account associated with the device on a PC, I can browse the Google Play store in a browser, and ask for apps to be remotely installed on the device. There's a permission prompt *on the website*, but the app gets downloaded and installed onto the device at the direction of Google, with no interaction or confirmation from the actual device.

How can I prevent this from happening? Do I have to root the device and remove Google Play and/or Google Play Services to prevent just any old apps from being "pushed" from Google's end and accepted by my device?

I need the device itself to remain trustworthy even if the Google account it is connected to is compromised.

Comment: This feels more like a [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) question than for SO. Once your Google account is compromised, they have the keys to everything Google related to that account (Gmail, search history, G Docs, G Photos, location history, etc.) so its either [TFA](https://www.google.com/landing/2step/) or as you suggest remove Google services entirely.

Answer (score 1):

This install is done by the Google Play app, so you would only have to remove this. However, this will probably do more to hurt the trustiworthiness of your device than help it. If you do this you will no longer get updates (including critical security updates) to Google Play Services.

A better option would be to add 2 factor authentication to the given Google account, and then you have the whole account protected by the device.